# PIC Microcontroller to Raspberry Pi Communication

Tags: wifi, ethernet, communication

I am designing a smart energy monitoring system as my FYP, I have used two pic18f452 microcontrollers to monitor the electric parameters and they are doing it successfully.

now to make it more user friendly, i am thinking to transmit the data which i have on my serial ports to the raspberry  and then on an internet server via wifi or ethernet.

please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Allot of energy monitors use 433mhz. This is a simple `Serial interface` 433mhz transciever only and you don't even have to do any code changes! You just connect your serial data UART TX, RX to the TX,RX (crossed), VCC and GND. Then on the Pi/Mac/PC/Arduino you attach another 433 Transceiver or receiver (You can get USB ones) and read UART. [Simple and cheap!](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/433MHz-Wireless-Serial-Port-Module-HC-11-/320849519761?pt=UK_Sound_Vision_Other&hash=item4ab41f2491)

[image]

As mentioned in the comments be carefull not to buy just the radio, then you have to use a library to encode and decode but thats even cheaper than a Serial Wireless 433mhz embedded.

Comment: RF transmitters don't quite work that way; you'll need some kind of protocol like Manchester Encoding to have a chance of the receiver picking up anything coherent.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I got the radio only. I updated to an embedded transparent serial wireless module, slightly more expensive but if you search around you can get some very cheap ones, especially if you buy in 5, 10 or more. Then all modules receive data from all other that send. Its really easy.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi has an available UART port so you could direct the PIC data to that port (pins 8/10 on P1).  The Pi is a 3.3V machine so if the PIC is outputting at 5V levels you will need to use a voltage divider on the PIC to Pi line.  The Pi to PIC direction should be fine.

See http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals for Pi pin outs and electrical details.

Then you write a C/Python/whatever program to do the rest.  Google for tutorials.

Comment: the microcontrollers transmits two serial frames simultaneously,and since it is a measurement device, i think USB would be must faster as compare to serial, is their a way i can send data to rpi using USB ports ?

Comment: You can buy serial to USB bridge hardware.  I'd imagine a software only solution would be very complicated.  What sort of data rates (bit rate and messages per second) are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to interface with multiple microcontrollers (in your post you mention two), you could use I2C. The PIC18F452 and the Pi have built-in support for I2C, which would allow you to talk with multiple PICs on just two wires. It could be a little harder to program if you're not familiar with how I2C works, though.

Answer (score 0):

I do like this for a temperature wireless sensor, with HC-12 433MHz module, 1 USB to my Rpi and 1 UART to a PIC18F13k22, it work well at more than 25m...

Answer (score -1):

Online PIC programming via USB port of a Raspberry Pi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S30wVi9RWEs. Programs available in https://www.dropbox.com/s/whwolbzf0cwkkb9/SanUSBrpi.zip

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.